# Chapter 9, Hartl ROR Section 9.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, railstutorial.org, before-filter

I Keep getting the same failure message, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Failures:

1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller visiting the edit page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
       expected css "title" with text "Sign in" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:69:in `block (6 levels) in '

2) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
     Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:74:in `block (6 levels) in '

Finished in 2.31 seconds
69 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:69 # Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller visiting the edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:74 # Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action

Here is the authentication_pages_spec.rb: 
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

```
subject { page }

describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end

describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
            before { click_link "Home" }
            it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
        end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
            fill_in "Email", with: user.email
            fill_in "Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Sign in"
        end

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
        it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

        describe "followed by signout" do
            before { click_link "Sign out" }
            it { should have_link('Sign in') }
        end
    end 
end

describe "with valid information" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before {sign_in user }

    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
end

describe "authorization" do

       describe "for non-signed-in users" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "in the Users controller" do

            describe "visiting the edit page" do
                before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
                it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
            end

            describe "submitting to the update action" do
                before { put user_path(user) }
                specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
            end
        end
       end
end
end
```

Here is the user_pages_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe "User Pages" do

```
subject { page }

describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
end

describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
        end

        describe "error messages" do
             before { click_button submit }

            it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
            it { should have_content('error') }
        end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
        before do
            fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
            fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
            fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
        end

        it "should create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

        describe "after saving the user" do
            before { click_button submit }
            let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

            it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
            it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
            it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        end
    end
end

describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user)}

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
end

describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
        sign_in user
        visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
        it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
        it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Save changes" }

        it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
        let(:new_name) { "New Name" }
        let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
        before do
            fill_in "Name", with: new_name
            fill_in "Email", with: new_email
            fill_in "Password", with: user.password
            fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Save changes"
        end

        it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
        specify { user.reload.name.should == new_name }
        specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the users_controller.rb:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        sign_in @user
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private

def signed_in_user
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
end
end
```

Here is the edit.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %> 
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the utilities.rb:

```
def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
        base_title
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
end

def sign_in(user)
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"

    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

here is the _header.html.erb:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Those are the files I've made changes to in Chapter 9, but if there are others that you think might be the problem please let me know and I can post them. Thanks!

Comment: It's a lot easier to read your question if you cut out irrelevant stuff - no need to include the specs that pass for example

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm a still a beginner, so I'm not 100% sure what's relevant info and what isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]` line at the top of your `UsersController`.  Take a look again at [Listing 9.12](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code:authorize_before_filter).